# Generate C# source code for model classes from database table schema for .Net 3.5 application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, object-relational-model

I create some WinForms apps using Ado.Net to connect the database. I'm using MVP model.

The application uses .Net 3.5 so I cannot use EF 5.0 and I am not willing to use lower version of EF. I'm using VS 2012 though. Is there any tool can be used to generate the C# model classes from the database table schema?

Comment: A link that shows how to do it through Visual Studio 2012 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

Comment: What is the latest version of EF you can use?

Comment: I think .Net 3.5 only support EF 1.0?

Comment: [Seems yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is called Entity Framework Model First: you generate Edmx designer-based model basing on existing database schema, and then POCO-classes basing on this model.

Visual Studio 2012 supports the approach by default: Add -> New item -> Data -> **EF 5.x DbContext Generator**.

Comment: The application uses .Net 3.5 so I cannot use EF 5.0 and I am not willing to use lower version of EF.

Comment: @NickW: Good reason for upgrade. You can try still [this addin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2) for VS2010 with latest version of EF supporting .NET 3.5.

Comment: Also check out [this addin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2).

Comment: It's a legacy application and I am stuck on .Net 3.5. I'm using Visual studio 2012 for the project though.

Comment: On my previous job we've migrated 1m lines of code legacy ASP.NET web forms app (started under .NET 1.x) to 3.5 and then 4.0 without any problems. All this talks, stucks and backward-compatibilities are **artificial**, imo.

Comment: I am not the owner of the application and it also depends on the .Net framework installed on the users' PC. Right now the IT department only installed .Net 3.5 on the desktops.

Comment: I see. Indeed that a reason but still I'm sorry to hear that yet another team is tuck with 3.5. Good to you though, not with 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is a windows tool available [SqlToCSharp](https://github.com/amit7verma/SqlToCSharp) which creates C# classes for Database tables, Views, SPs etc.

I have developed it, I am sure it will be helpful to solve the mentioned issue.